# Inconsistent accessibility: return type is less accessible than method while using interface in C#

Tags: c#, oop

Here is my code

I have defined interface with one property and one method.

```
interface IBusService
{
    string ServiceProviderName { get; set; }
    List<RouteDetails> GetAvailableServices();
}
```

I have created implementation for the interface in below class

```
public class MayanBusService : IBusService
{
    public MayanBusService()
    {
        this.ServiceProviderName = "Mayan Bus Service";
    }
    public string ServiceProviderName { get; set; }

    public List<RouteDetails> GetAvailableServices()
    {
        List<RouteDetails> availableRoutes = new List<RouteDetails>();

        availableRoutes.Add(new RouteDetails()
        {
            FromLocation = "X",
            ToLocation = "Y",
            StartTime = new TimeSpan(10, 10, 00),
            EndTime = new TimeSpan(11, 00, 00)
        });

        return availableRoutes;
    }
}
```

When I am trying to use "List" then I am getting following exception.

Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' is less accessible than method 'BusServiceProvider.BusServiceComparer.CompareBusService(System.Collections.Generic.List)

```
public class BusServiceComparer
    {
        List<IBusService> availableBusProviders = new List<IBusService>();
        public BusServiceComparer()
        {
            availableBusProviders.Add(new VeenaBusService());
            availableBusProviders.Add(new MayanBusService());
        }

        public void CompareBusService(List<IBusService> availableBuses)
        {
            //Problem starts here
        }
    }
```

Any help would be much appriciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: a simple google search with "Inconsistent accessibility: return type is less accessible than method" yields plenty of results.

Comment: Or click on the error code in VS